# laravel: double foreach loop returns a record twice?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reference

I have two for eachloop in laravel blade, that is why it give me each record two times.

```
@foreach($notes = $notes->sortBy(function ($note) {
        return ($note->active ? '0' : '1') . ($note->status('health') == 'down' ? '0' : '1') . ($note->status('speed'));
    }); as $notification)


        @foreach ($notification->statuses as $timestamp)
            <tr> 
                <td> {{ $notification->website_url }} </td>
                @if($notification->status('health') == 'up')
                    <td> {{ $notification->status('health') }} <span class="up"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_green">{{$timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>.
                @elseif($notification->status('health') == 'down')
                    <td> {{ $notification->status('health') }}  <span class="down"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_red">{{$timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>
                @else
                    <td> {{ $notification->status('health') }}  <span class="unsigned"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_unsigned">{{$timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>
                @endif 
                @if((int)$notification->status('speed'))
                    @if($notification->status('speed') <= 59)
                        <td> {{ $notification->status('speed') }} <span class="down"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_red">{{ $timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>
                    @elseif($notification->status('speed') >=60 && $notification->status('speed') <= 79)
                        <td> {{ $notification->status('speed') }} <span class="improve"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_improve">{{ $timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>
                    @elseif($notification->status('speed') >= 80)
                        <td> {{ $notification->status('speed') }}<span class="up"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_green">{{ $timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>
                    @endif
                @else
                    <td> {{ $notification->status('speed') }} <span class="unsigned"></span>.<br><span class="timestamp_unsigned">{{ $timestamp->pivot->created_at }}</span></td>       
                @endif
                <td>                         
                    {{ $notification->active == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('aileen'))
                        <a href="{{ route('notifications.edit', [$notification->id]) }}">
                            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"/>
                        </a>
                    @endif
                    <a href="{{ route('history',[$notification->id]) }}">
                        <input type="submit" name="history" value="history"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach 
</tbody>
```

one one gave give me a better way to do it? my second foreach loop to access the data or timestamp in the pivote table.

Comment: Why are you doing the second foreach and not using `$timestamp` variable?

Comment: in order to access the time stamp in the pivot table. i have many to many relationship